# Perfect rounded corner using Shape

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-selector

How can I make a perfect rounded corner? I have tried everything, but it is not coming out as I expected. Please help me out. Below is my code. By using that code, I am getting the image below.

XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_background_five">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/settingshover" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

tab_background_five.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_five" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_five_white" android:state_selected="false" />
```

tab_bg_five.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#CF5548" />
<corners
    android:radius="3dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
```

[image: This is the edge i am getting from the above code]

Comment: Same thing without the imageview margin ?

Comment: yes without margin too

Comment: You need these two to be `android:bottomRightRadius="HHdp"
    android:topRightRadius="HHdp" />` where **HH** is half of the height. Anyway, you aren't using `shape.xml` anywhere.

Comment: i used it on the frame layout

Comment: its tab layout how can set it half of height sir @Rotwang

Comment: where are you using `Selector.xml`? in which xml layout?

Comment: i had updated the Question please check it

Comment: your view `id/first_ll` has height > `60dp`, thats why you have no `"perfect round corner"`

Comment: then how can i solve it @pskink

Comment: ypu have to set its height to 60dp?

Comment: i had solved it by making it into wrap content

Comment: **1** You don't need nesting 2 FrameLayouts. One level is enough. **2** Try setting `android:layout_height="60dp"` in your FrameLayout.